# which mysqli query need mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Connection file is as below

```
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="123";
$database = "order";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
$sel_db=mysqli_select_db($con,$database) or die("Cannot Select Database");
```

In each file I include above connection file

My older code for mysql is like

```
mysql_query("select * from order_detail");
```

and new query for mysqli is as below

```
mysqli_query($con,"select * from order_detail");
```

Above query required $con for connection

and `mysql_fetch_array($var)` becomes `mysqli_fetch_array($var)` it does not required $con

`mysql_real_escape_string($var)` becomes `mysql_real_escape_string($con,$var);`

So my question is that which query required $con as connection

Comment: If only there was a website which documented this... http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: What do you mean by wich query? And I would suggest you to use MySQLi's prepared statement functions instead of `mysqli_query();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` functions implicitly used the last connection that was made if no connection was explicitly given. Note that you already could pass in a connection, even to the old function as you can [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). This behavior is confusing and error prone, so fortunately they made that more explicit in the `mysqli` functions.

I'm not sure that is the main reason though. It probably might have more to do with the fact that mysqli also has an object syntax, and that one syntax wraps another. The `$con` variable in the procedural version and the object instance in the objective version both serve the same purpose: telling the function/method which connection to use. Actually, [the doc says](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) that the connection parameter for `mysqli_query` is a mysqli object instance, so mysqli_query might just be implemented like this as a wrapper function to make it easier to convert your code from mysql to mysqli:

```
function mysqli_query($link, $query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
  return $link->query($query, $resultmode);
}
```

If you didn't understand anything I said in this last paragraph, don't worry, it's not really important. ;)

Anyway, while `mysql_query` performs a query on a connection, `mysql_fetch_array` fetches values from a query *result*. The `$var` your pass to it already contains all the information it needs. It doesn't need a connection at that point, so there is no need to pass it as an argument. There is no `mysqli_fetch_array` by the way. Instead you should use `mysqli_stmt_fetch`, to which the same applies: it doesn't need a connection, but a statement object (mysqli_stmt), which represents the query result.

Many of the mysqli functions have the same or similar parameters as their predecessors, but there may be differences. So for every function you use, I'd check [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

And also, I'd use an IDE or editor that will help you with the function syntax by providing built in code insight. [Netbeans for PHP](https://netbeans.org/features/php/) is a quite elaborate one that can be used for free, but there are even better ones (like PHPStorm) if you can spend some money.

PS: If you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), you can get rid of `mysql_real_escape_string` completely.

Comment: you means that if we give connection to first query then no need to give second mysqli_query

Comment: No. The list of arguments is fixed based on the implementation, regardless in which order you use the functions. I've extended my answer a bit, but the core is: not all functions are exactly the same between mysql and mysqli, so you should check the linked documentation to see exactly which arguments you need to pass.